# Fixing an infix parser

Tags: parsing, math

I have a mathematical expression parser that should handle `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `^`, `(-)`, functions, and of course atoms (such as `x`, `1`, `pi`, etc.).  The parser is basically designed according to [Wikipedia's operator precedence parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator-precedence_parser), which I've reproduced below; `parse_primary()` is defined elsewhere.

```
parse_expression ()
    return parse_expression_1 (parse_primary (), 0)

parse_expression_1 (lhs, min_precedence)
    while the next token is a binary operator whose precedence is >= min_precedence
        op := next token
        rhs := parse_primary ()
        while the next token is a binary operator whose precedence is greater
                 than op's, or a right-associative operator
                 whose precedence is equal to op's
            lookahead := next token
            rhs := parse_expression_1 (rhs, lookahead's precedence)
        lhs := the result of applying op with operands lhs and rhs
    return lhs
```

How can I modify this parser to handle `(-)` correctly?  Better yet, how can I implement a parser with support for all infix and postfix operators (`!` for instance) that I might want?  Finally, how should functions be treated?

I should note that `(-)` negation is distinguished in the lexer from `-` "subtraction", so it can be treated as a different token.

Comment: Simply let `^` take precedence over unary `-`? As it currently stands, this question doesn't contain enough information and is very difficult to answer.

Comment: phant0m, I've modified my question (it **was** a bit vague), although I'm not quite asking the same question now.  I think I will rewrite the parser I have, which is quite hairy, to match whatever answers I get here.

Comment: Very subjective, but... Small advice. Make it shorter. Be more specific. No small talk. As it currently stand it is to long for me to bother. (Better yet, talking too much perhaps. Implement your algorithm in Python. Then we have something to talk about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All unary operators and function call stuff basically belongs in the parse_primary, which should accept a legal unary term.

Comment: I see.  So parse_primary should look ahead one token to ensure it is not a postfix operator?